# How to count number of occurances of a text in a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, textrange

```
var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
  textRange.collapse(true);
  if( textRange.findText(tex)) {
    textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
}
```

The above code is perfect to search for text and highlight it in IE but I want to do a little amendment to count the number of occurrences as well. Like below

```
textRange.findText(tex).WhichMethod()  Should i use to return me count of occurrences.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to count the number of instances of a particular pattern, then something like the following should suit:

```
function countString(s) {
  var re = new RegExp(s, 'gi');
  var b = document.body;

  // Make an assumption about support for textContent and inerText
  var text = typeof b.textContent == 'string'? b.textContent : b.innerText;
  var matches = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').match(re);

  return matches? matches.length : 0;
}
```